# fail to send out email by kaa admin

Tags: kaa

I clone kaa source code from git, and succeed built and run it on my ubuntu 14.04.
and then I also succeed to create kaa admin.

and then I set my outgoing email settings as this

- **SMTP Protocol**: smtps
- **SMTP Host**: smtp.gmail.com
- **SMTP Port**: 465
- **Username**: myemailaddress@gmail.com
- **Password**: mypassword

and then I went to create a tenant, then add a user:

- **Username**: admin
- **Email**: myanotheremail@xxx.com
- **Account role**: Tenane Administrator

but I fail to sent out the email to the tenant user from kaa server (or I did not receive the mail from kaa admin)

I also change the log level to **TRACE** and restart service, but there seems no error or trace information about this scenario in it.

would someone please help guide me what to do to make it work?

Many thanks
Vincent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your outgoing email settings looks correct.
Looks like for Google accounts, you need to allow less secure apps to access accounts. Follow the [official guide](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255) to do this.

Comment: Hi Oleksandr, I 've already set my gmail account low security before submitting the question. thanks for your reply.

Comment: Could you check the branch that you built?
You can use the "release-0.9" branch with Kaa 0.9.0 version or "release-0.10" branch (previously called "develop") with unreleased Kaa 0.10.0-SNAPSHOT version. Temporary in the Kaa 0.10.0-SNAPSHOT version was a problem with send email with temp password, see the [jira ticket](http://jira.kaaproject.org/browse/KAA-1442). Could you rebuild Kaa from latest "release-0.10" or "release-0.9.0" branch?

Comment: Thanks, I did rebuilt to release-0.9.0 from the oringal branch (maybe master?) yesterday and fix my typo on the smtp server, then it works. thanks a lot